# ¿Cómo poner que si una cadena no está dentro de mi secuencia de caracteres, entonces poner el predeterminado?

Tags: java, poo

La cosa es que ya tengo creada mi clase, pero no se cómo poner que la variable String nombre, si es diferente a alguno de los que están dentro de String[], entonces devolver el valor por defecto, el cual en este caso quiero que sea "Programación".

```
    public class Materia {
    public static final String[] nombresMaterias ={"THC", "Programación", "Manejo de datos"};
    private String nombre;

    public Materia(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre){
       if(!"THC".equals(nombre)){ 
          this.nombre = "Programación";
       } else{
          nombre = this.nombre;
       }
   }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
       return "Materia: " + nombre;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería bueno que tengas el valor por defecto en una constante dentro de la clase para evitar inconsistencias:

```
public class Materia {
    private static final String DEFAULT = "Programación";

    public static final String[] nombresMaterias = {"THC", DEFAULT, "Manejo de datos"};
    private String nombre = DEFAULT;

    public Materia(String nombre){
        this.setNombre(nombre);
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        if(this.existe(nombre))
            this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    private boolean existe(String nombre) {
        for(String materia : nombresMaterias) {
            if(materia.equals(nombre))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Materia: " + nombre;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setNombre(String nombre){
       // variable para indicar si existe o no en el arreglo
       boolean existe = false;
       // recorrer el arreglo nombresMaterias
       for(String materia : nombresMaterias){
           // si algún elemento es igual al nombre entonces existe = true y salir
           if(materia.equals(nombre){ existe = true;break;}

       }
       // si no existe asignar valor por defecto
       if(!existe) this.nombre = "Programación";
       else this.nombre = nombre;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// valor por defecto
private String valorPorDefecto = "Programación";

public Materia(String nombre) {
    // usa la función setNombre(nombre) en el constructor
    setNombre(nombre);  
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    if(existe(nombre) { // invocar la función privada existe(nombre), si es true, entonces:
        this.nombre = nombre; // se asigna el valor del parámetro
    } else { // si es false, entonces:
        this.nombre = valorPorDefecto; // se asigna el valor por defecto
    }
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

/*
    función privada que verifica si el nombre de la materia 
    existe en el arreglo de materias
*/
private boolean existe(String nombre) {
    if(nombre == null){ // si nombre es igual a null, retorna false;
        return false;
    }

    // recorrer el arreglo de materias
    for(int i = 0; i < nombresMaterias.length; i++){
       // comparar cada materia con el parámetro nombre
       if(nombresMaterias[i].equals(nombre){ // si son iguales retorna true;
           return true;
       }
    }        

    return false; // retorna false, porque se recorrió el arreglo y no se encontró el nombre
}
```